# Unit test abstract class with injected service

Tags: unit-testing, grails, dependency-injection, abstract-class, spock

My application has a set of subclasses that all extend a certain base class.

**BaseClass.groovy**

```
abstract class Base {

    def beforeInsert() {
        userCreated = springSecurityService.currentUser
    }

    /* other stuff */

}
```

**ConcreteClass.groovy**

```
class Concrete extends Base {

    /* stuff, doesn't matter */

}
```

And I am writing a test that must instantiate several Concretes:

**RelatedServiceSpec.groovy**

```
def "under x circumstances, check for all instances that meet y criteria"() {

  setup: "create 3 concrete classes"
     (1..3).each { new Concrete(a: 'yes').save(validate: false) }

    /* and then the actual test ... */

}
```

The problem arises when I save the instances, because of that `springSecurityService` up in `BaseClass`. I can't find a way to stub it out for the unit test!

- I can't `@Mock` an abstract class, which is needed to use `defineBeans`.
- `Base.springSecurityService` raises an NPE.
- `Base.metaClass.springSecurityService` and `Base.metaClass.static.springSecurityService` compile but don't work.
- And apparently you can't override events in Grails, so I can't just bypass the `beforeInsert`, which would be fine.

Anybody know how to unit test an abstract class with an injected service?

**EDIT**

It hadn't occurred to me to inject the service into the implementation class! I'll give it a try!

Comment: how do you deal with the userCreated if there is no session/springSecurity at all?  e.g. a batch job creating those objects or in bootstrap?

Comment: That issue has not arisen. They are currently only created directly by a user, or as a side-effect of another action by a user.  How should it be handled, and is that a clue for how to handle this situation?

Comment: i just wanted to know or raise the point.  if they can be null, just use springSecurityService?.currentUser or if there is a default user (system, admin, ...) just assign this one there.  the original question stays valid regardless.

Comment: After thinking about it, I don't think this is an optional field, and there's not a default user. And I don't like the idea of altering the code in order to pass the test. Maybe I should just make `Base` concrete...

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you create an implementation of `beforeInsert()` that `beforeInsert()` calls and that you then override in derived classes for your tests?  I haven't tried this, so I don't know if it will work, but it might be worth a shot before making `Base` concrete.

```
abstract class Base {

    def beforeInsert() {
        beforeInsertImpl()
    }

    def beforeInsertImpl() {
        userCreated = springSecurityService.currentUser
    }

    /* other stuff */
}
```

Within tests:

```
setup: "create 3 concrete classes"
     (1..3).each {
         def concrete = new Concrete(a: 'yes')
         concrete.metaClass.beforeInsertImpl { /* do something with userCreated here */}
         concrete.save(validate: false)
     }
```

Comment: Not a bad idea, might have to try it if injecting the service into the derived class doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
Concrete.metaClass.getSpringSecurityService = {
    return [
        getCurrentUser: {
            return new User()
        }
    ] as SpringSecurityService
}
```

can you try this?
of course, this should go before calling new Concrete()

Comment: It hadn't occurred to me to inject the service into the implementation class! I'll give it a try!